# Is there are a way to add Multi Agent layer into a game development ?

Tags: unity-game-engine, jmonkeyengine, multi-agent

I am hoping to build a RTS game for my final year project. Is there are a way to add Multi Agent layer into a game development ? I am hoping to use unity 3d or JMoneky

Comment: Short answer: "Yes" (as anything is possible to do in software). But I assume you're actually asking how to do it, which is way too broad.

Comment: can you tell where i can find resources as how to do this?